# find object (artifical intelligence or opencv)

Tags: opencv, object, find

I want to find blue shoes in video For exaample blue boat,blue sport shoes,blue buskin) But where should I start? Is it connected to artifical intellegence or only can do it opencv  ?
If it connected to artifical intelligence how can I do it ? Any example ?
Thanks your advise

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not complex task. you do not need any AI concepts. It is simple image processing problem. Since you mentioned OpenCV:

1. Convert your image to the HSV color space.
2. Use inRange function to cut out the pixels with blue range.
3. bitwise-and  between the mask you got from inRange and you image

However, it seems that you do not have a background in OpenCV. You should find some tutorial in the programing language you know.

Comment: ok! thanks but no blue shoes If I want to only shoes how can I do it

Comment: That is much complex , you will need to deep into object detection and recognition (classification or contour analysing ...)

Comment: Actually my advisor say " you should do use artifical intelligance this project "

Comment: hmm but unfortunately I have to this  with artifical intelligence :( but how?

Comment: In order to do object detection and recognition, you probably need classification methods which are considering part of the Machine Learning or Artificial intelligence. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199056/machine-learning-ai-and-soft-computing

Comment: becouse I have done it your method (I use inrange  vs... but he rejected me:(

Comment: "but how?" You need to find some good theoretical book and another one for application in the programming language you are familiar with. So fist step is to step into your university library and find them or to ask your supervisor for an advice

Comment: Ok! thank you so much  I have found a book Generally I study c/c++ Is it a good language for artifical intelligence or Should I find another programming language?

Comment: there is no good or bad one. c/c++ is not the best choice for academic environment, you may just use some program like Matlab

Comment: hmm my adviser support me about c/c++ this project but I can talk this issue with him

Comment: But yet may be c/c++ can use ?

Comment: Anything could be used. Since you want to use C++, see OpenCV it was written in C and wrapped for C++.

Comment: Welcome and do not forget to accept the answer if you found it useful. (use the green tick on the left of it.